# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, matriz, numpy

O programa abaixo serve para calcular duas matrizes (w1 e w2) e, a partir deles, calcular uma f´rmula (chama-se matriz de transmissão) e após isso pegar os resultados dessa matriz e fazer o traçõ da multiplicação entre a matriz de transmissão e sua transposta. Até então tava pegando certinho, até que eu coloquei esse x pra ele poder fazer o loop no programa inteiro, fazendo com que gerasse o problema citado acima. Quando eu tiro esse x, o programa pega normal. Pq dá esse erro e oq posso fazer pra poder consertar?  Ficarei grato pela ajuda, pois sou iniciante na linguagem e não sei de muitas funcionalidade. Segue o que eu conseguir fazer até então:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cmath

n1=n2=1
w1 = []
w2 = []
g = []
E = 0
i = 1j  
pi = math.pi
M = 200

#valores usados pra montar minha matriz
gama1 = 1
b1 = math.sqrt(gama1) / (1+math.sqrt(1-gama1)) 

gama2 = 0.8
b2 = math.sqrt(gama2) / (1+math.sqrt(1-gama2))

x = int(input('valor: ')) #valor usado pra fazer um loop 
 
#matriz 1
for k in range(1, x+1):
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(n1):
            w1.append(b1*math.sqrt(1/(pi * (M+1)))*math.sin(((i+1)*(j+1)*pi) / (M+1)))
    w1 = np.array(w1) #transformando a lisa em um array numpy
    print(f'MATRIX W1 \n {w1}')

    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(n2):
            w2.append(b2*math.sqrt(1/(pi * (M+1)))*math.sin(((i+1)*(j+1)*pi) / (M+1)))
    w2 = np.array(w2)
    print(f'MATRIX W2 \n {w2}')

    np.savetxt('dados.dat', [w1,w2], delimiter=",") # salvo os valores das matrizes no arquvio "dados.dat"

    H = np.random.rand (M,M)  #matriz hamiltoniana
    formula1 = -2*pi*w1.T*i #parte do cálculo
    formula2 = E - H + pi*i #parte do cálculo
    multiplication = (w1+w1.T) * (w2+w2.T) # soma da multiplicação entre as matrizes e suas transpostas
    print(f'VALOR DA MULTIPLICAÇÃO IGUAL A : {multiplication}')

    t = formula1*((formula2*(multiplication))**(-1))*w2 #cálculo completo
    print(t)

    for k in range(x):
        g.append(np.trace(t*t.T)) #criação do vetor g pra armazenar o valor do traço da multiplicação entre t e a transposta de t
    g = np.array(g)#transformo a lista em array
    print(f' valores de g = [{g}]')
```

espero que tenha ficado claro e qualquer dúvida, se eu souber responder, respondo
agradeço a quem puder me ajudar :)

Comment: O erro ocorre porqque voce está convertendo a lista para numpy.ndarray na linha 28 e na linha 34. Isso faz a lista(que agora é ndarray) perder o metodo na iteração seguinte, pois deixou de ser uma lista.

Comment: obrigadoooooooooo

Answer (score 1):

O erro está ocorrendo porque voce está convertendo as listas para o tipo ndarray na linha 28(w1), na linha 34(w2) e na linha 55(g). Isso faz a lista(que agora é ndarray) perder o metodo na iteração seguinte, pois deixou de ser uma lista.

Declare as 3 listas w1, w2, g dentro do primeiro for.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cmath

n1 = n2 = 1
E = 0
i = 1j
pi = math.pi
M = 200

# valores usados pra montar minha matriz
gama1 = 1
b1 = math.sqrt(gama1) / (1+math.sqrt(1-gama1))

gama2 = 0.8
b2 = math.sqrt(gama2) / (1+math.sqrt(1-gama2))

x = int(input('valor: '))  # valor usado pra fazer um loop

# matriz 1
for k in range(1, x+1):
    w1 = []
    w2 = []
    g = []
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(n1):
            w1.append(b1*math.sqrt(1/(pi * (M+1))) *
                    math.sin(((i+1)*(j+1)*pi) / (M+1)))
    w1 = np.array(w1)  # transformando a lisa em um array numpy
    print(f'MATRIX W1 \n {w1}')

    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(n2):
            w2.append(b2*math.sqrt(1/(pi * (M+1))) *
                    math.sin(((i+1)*(j+1)*pi) / (M+1)))
    w2 = np.array(w2)
    print(f'MATRIX W2 \n {w2}')

    # salvo os valores das matrizes no arquvio "dados.dat"
    np.savetxt('dados.dat', [w1, w2], delimiter=",")

    H = np.random.rand(M, M)  # matriz hamiltoniana
    formula1 = -2*pi*w1.T*i  # parte do cálculo
    formula2 = E - H + pi*i  # parte do cálculo
    # soma da multiplicação entre as matrizes e suas transpostas
    multiplication = (w1+w1.T) * (w2+w2.T)
    print(f'VALOR DA MULTIPLICAÇÃO IGUAL A : {multiplication}')

    t = formula1*((formula2*(multiplication))**(-1))*w2  # cálculo completo
    print(t)

    for k in range(x):
        # criação do vetor g pra armazenar o valor do traço da multiplicação entre t e a transposta de t
        g.append(np.trace(t*t.T))
    g = np.array(g)  # transformo a lista em array
    print(f' valores de g = [{g}]')
```